# using Xpath function in wso2 esb

Tags: xml, xpath, mediator, wso2-esb

I am trying to use fn:contains as xpath condition in wso2 esb filter mediator.

I need to find whether the following pattern :// is present in a given string. Hence I saved the string (address) in a property and called that property from filter mediator.

address = mq://xxx.xxx.xx@xx.xx.xx

I have tried below combinations and nothing worked

```
fn:contains('get-property('address')','://')
fn:contains(get-property('address'),'://')
fn:contains("get-property('address')",'://')
```

If I give the address string itself instead of get-property it worked! also the below combination worked

```
"fn:contains(get-property('address'),'://')"
```

but after saving, the above mentioned xpath is not getting displayed in the design view. XPATH was empty.

Any inputs on this issue please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are having 'fun with quotes'. To work around this you can use $ctx in stead of get-property().  $ctx is a [Synapse xpath variable](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Synapse+XPath+Variables#SynapseXPathVariables-$ctx) that allows you to access properties that are set on default scope. You can check the link for other xpath variables.

Try using:

```
"fn:contains($ctx:address,'://')"
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer  solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.